# Update ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 on a dual booted laptop without uninstalling windows

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, update-manager, windows-10

If I were to update to ubuntu 15.04 from 14.04 through the ubuntu software updater on a dual booted laptop with windows 10, would the update uninstall windows 10 on my laptop?

Comment: Of course it wouldn't, but you can't upgrade directly to 15.04...you would have to upgrade thru 14.10 and then to 15.04; also consider 15.04 support ends this month.

Comment: are you sure I can't? It gives me the option to upgrade.

Comment: It should only let you upgrade from one version to the next consecutive version, and not let you skip a version, or from one LTS version to the next consecutive LTS version. Read what it's offering to do carefully.

Comment: It says I'm up to date. Then it says , "However ubuntu 15.04 is available." Then it gives me an option to upgrade. I'm on 14.04. Is it safe to update to 15.04?